# Child view not working in angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is the code:

```
$stateProvider.
  state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard/',
    templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/views/dashboard.client.view.html',
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
  }).
  state('dashboard-home', {
    url: '/dashboard/home/',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/views/home.client.view.html'
  });
```

I have a `<div ui-view></div>` element in *dashboard.client.view.html*

When I navigate to `/dashboard/home/` nothing comes up. The goal is to have `home.client.view.html` get injected into `dashboard.client.view.html`.

Comment: Are you looking for nested views? If yes then try this state('dashboard.dashboard-home', {   }); This tells the browser that "dashboard-home" is a nested view of "dashboard". If No, then please explain your question a little more.

Comment: Hi, when i look at this doc (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) , i see that ui-view need an Id. Maybe you have to do this in your div:

           <div ui-view="dashboard-home"></div>

Comment: @kurenaiKunai Yes, I am looking for nested views. I already that and it  is not working. The "parent" attribute is supposed to do the same thing though, is it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [an example as working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nh05uoPkMcJPNsWHw3W6?p=preview)

Each `Child` state inherits **url** from its `Parent`. So we shoulduse just

```
url: '/home',
```

because parent will add the `/dashboard`.

The state definition has changed url in our child state:

```
.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/views/dashboard.client.view.html',
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
  })
.state('dashboard-home', {
    //url: '/dashboard/home/',
    url: '/home',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/views/home.client.view.html'
});
```

And these links are working as expected:

```
<a href="#/dashboard">
<a href="#/dashboard/home">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nh05uoPkMcJPNsWHw3W6?p=preview)

There is [another working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/36iy5Xph9JGO6yj9lf6V?p=preview), which shows that we can map states without `parent:''`, but with dot notation:

```
state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/views/dashboard.client.view.html',
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
})
//.state('dashboard-home', {
.state('dashboard.home', {
    //url: '/dashboard/home/',
    url: '/home', 
    templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/views/home.client.view.html'
});
```

You can observe it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/36iy5Xph9JGO6yj9lf6V?p=preview)

Comment: your "Check it in action [here]' link didn't get linked correctly.

Comment: @DrCord Thanks a lot ...going to fix it

Comment: Thanks. This little detail cost me a lot of time.